# re-arranged categories 404 errors

Tags: seo

I need some SEO advise.

I recently redesigned my website an the impact is huge. That's the good part.
I also re-arranged the categories and some pages are not there anymore. Example:

- in the past I had **10** pages of the category premium SEO tips, but after the redesign there are only **5** pages of the category left.

Googlebot is going wild on those missing 5 category pages and I get lots of 404s.

The thing is later page number 6 and 7 and 8 etc will be there, but not at the moment.

I'm afraid of use a 410 for those pages.
Any other options? Or just leaving it a 404?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just submit a new sitemap to google? It worked for me. Alternatively you could redirect via htaccess all the missing urls, but just resubmitting a sitemap on webmasters tools should do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the first thing I did, but Googlebot is still going to the old pages. And I told Google not to index (only follow) my category pages.

Comment: that's a bit weird...htaccess redirect then? 301 should do it. I'm not sure of the SEO implications, because I don't care that much though

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. Next month page number 6 will be there and I have just told Google with a 301 that the page have permanently moved to what page? Page number 1 or 2 or 3? Bad idea.
Ow, and my question is about SEO implications.

Comment: well then we have to wait for someone else. Google has never done that to me - I've wiped out a site and rebuilt it, with a new sitemap everything's fine. The 404 errors I got were coming from clicks on links previsouly shared on social networks and such. It wasn't Google. When I decided that the page wasn't going to be there anymore for good, I put a nice 301 redirect and that was it. I don't see why you couldn't go for a 302 if you're putting them back. 404 isn't good for SEO I'd say.

Comment: and by the way, there's a discussion about the topic [here](http://moz.com/blog/are-404-pages-always-bad-for-seo). As far as I can see, there's no option that everyone accepts. When there's nothing sure, focus on user experience, not on robots. Basically, resubmit sitemap, add some relevant custom error page or a redirect to a relevant section, you can also block the urls in robots.txt (as suggested [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38603/why-do-410-pages-show-as-errors-in-google-webmaster-tools), wait.

Comment: I'm a bit afraid of the 302 in this case, because some page take a month but other 6 months to appear again. Maybe I can do a 302 for the pages that will come back within a month.
I agree with 404 isn't good for SEO either. User experience is more important.
I think I am going for 301 for some pages, 302 some more, and 404 for the ones that won't come back within 3 months. All category pages all blocked by the way.